# How to save data in cookie in express?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, express-session

How can i save data in my session cookie while my cooike his in `{secure : true}`?

Now my cookie restart every request to the server and the data been removed.

My cookie look like this :

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1)
app.use(session({
     proxy:true,
     resave:true,
     secret: process.env.SECRET,
     cookie: {secure : true, maxAge : 8 * 60 * 60 *1000,sameSite: "none", httpOnly:false},
     credentials:true,
     saveUninitialized:true,

})
)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are testing your express application on your local network you aren't going to be able to use `{secure: true}`. This is because the local host version is `http://` not `https://`.

To be able to save data inside of the cookies once a request is made you can use:

```js
req.session.username = 'username here';
```

As long as the server hasn't be restarted this variable can then be acessed again inside of a requets like this:

```js
console.log(`Username: ${req.session.username}`);
```

Check out the Express Sessions Docs [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html) too.

Hope this helps! Thanks

Comment: I use it inside domain,not on my local PC